# jQuery plugin to parse tweets from multiple users

Tags: jquery, loops, twitter

On a site that I am building I have 3 personal profiles, in these profiles, along with general information I want to display that persons latest tweet. I managed to find a tutorial over at: http://www.queness.com/post/8567/create-a-dead-simple-twitter-feed-with-jquery which seemed really good and is fairly light-weight.

The only problem with this code is that I want to include multiple users, but am unsure how to go about it, or if it is even going to be possible with this code.

The current state of the code (without the time calculator) is as follows:

```
// Set twitter username, number of tweets & id/class to append tweets
user: 'theresidency',
numTweets: 1,
appendTo: '#twit_contain_res .bubble',

// core function of jqtweet
loadTweets: function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json/',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data: {
            screen_name: JQTWEET.user,
            include_rts: true,
            count: JQTWEET.numTweets,
            include_entities: true
        },
        success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {

             var html = '<div class="tweet">TWEET_TEXT<b><div class="time">AGO</b></div>';

             // append tweets into page
             for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                $(JQTWEET.appendTo).append(
                    html.replace('TWEET_TEXT', JQTWEET.ify.clean(data[i].text) )
                        .replace(/USER/g, data[i].user.screen_name)
                        .replace('AGO', JQTWEET.timeAgo(data[i].created_at) )
                        .replace(/ID/g, data[i].id_str)
                );
             }                  
        }   

    });

}, `
```

I was trying to think how I could implement a loop to check for multiple users, but am unsure how to go about it.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated, so thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You already have your loop

```
 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   switch(data[i].user.screen_name){
   case "that_user":
   //do something
   break;

   case "other_user":
   //do something else
   break;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply dude, I'm obviously doing something wrong but I can't seem to figure out what, am I including the code in the wrong place? My modified code is here: http://pastie.org/3650214

Comment: var appendTo = '#twit_contain_res .bubble';  $(appendTo).append(

Comment: in fact, var appendTo = '#twit_contain_res'; $(appendTo).append(

Comment: sorry dude, i'm still getting to grips with jquery! Do I include the variable within each case? Feel free to edit that pastie if its easier: http://pastie.org/3650214

Comment: You can declare the variable before the loop (like var appenTo;), then give it a value.

Comment: again, thanks for the help dude. I have done what you suggested (see http://pastie.org/3657379) but it still isn't working. I just cant figure out why, from what I understand I can't see anything thats missing :S I really appreciate the help!

Comment: I see many mistakes and it tells me most of it isn't your code :)  $(JQTWEET.appendTo).append(  should be $(appendTo).append( as i wrote before, also why do you do append and replace ?? It doesn't make sens.

Comment: well, thats good (I suppose) haha. I've fixed that bit you said about but it's still not functioning, not sure why either. I followed this tutorial for it: http://www.queness.com/post/8567/create-a-dead-simple-twitter-feed-with-jquery ... so i've no idea why .replace is used, I thought it was only used in regepx to replace words etc.